# Prevent Keyup event on second time in Jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox, replication, keyup

I have 5 text-boxes for [ Title, Name, Keyword, Description and URL] input

```
$("#TxtPageTitle").keyup(function () {
  $("#TxtPageName").val($(this).val());
  $("#TxtPageKeywords").val($(this).val());
  $("#TxtPageDescription").val($(this).val());
  $("#TxtPageURL").val($(this).val());
});
```

I'm using JQuery's Keyup event to handle replication, When I type something in Title (text-box) it'll get filled in all other 4 text-boxes.

Problem is: I'll first type something in Title (text-box) and it'll filled in all other text-boxes and later I'll edit the values of all 4 text-boxes. again if change the value Title (text-box) then old values of all other 4 text-boxes will be changed.

What I want is The Keyup method should only work on first entry. so I can prevent this problem.

Comment: Can you provide html source or jsfiddle.net

Comment: Just `.unbind()` the `keyup` when you want the results to stay static: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: @gdoron But that way the user will only be able to enter "one" character - the OP says *When I type something in Title* which I would guess is more than one character. See: http://jsfiddle.net/qLyKx/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to give the fields that you want to fill automatically a particular class, say "autoFill", and then remove that class from the individual fields when they are modified, e.g.,:

```
$("#TxtPageTitle").keyup(function () {
    $(".autoFill").val(this.value);
});

$(".autoFill").change(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("autoFill");
});​​​​​​​​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A2FsY/

You said "on first entry", but what I'm suggesting goes one better than that in that it will continue to apply the changes from #TxtPageTitle to any of the other fields that have not yet been individually edited. If you really want it to be "on first entry" only then add a `.blur()` or `.change()` handler to #TxtPageTitle as per Blade0rz's answer.

EDIT: Note that there is no need to keep firing the change event on fields that no longer have the "autoFill" class, so the body of the change handler above could be changed to:

```
$(this).removeClass("autoFill").unbind("change");
```

Answer (score 2):

The keyup event will fire every time you type 1 character in the textbox. There is no way to tell how much characters the first edit has. Either you decide a fixed value for the number of characters in the textbox, after which the keyup event gets unbinded, or you add a command for the user to "tell" when he has stopped typing, and then unbind the event. To unbind the event refer to: [jQuery unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Answer (score 0):

You could unbind the keyup handler when the page title textbox loses focus. That would mostly indicate the user has finished:

```
$("#TxtPageTitle").keyup(function () {
  $("#TxtPageName").val($(this).val());
  $("#TxtPageKeywords").val($(this).val());
  $("#TxtPageDescription").val($(this).val());
  $("#TxtPageURL").val($(this).val());
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).unbind("keyup");
});
```

Comment: I like the idea of the lose focus which is really smart, but i think that this solution is not OK, since we cannot be sure that the user will unfocus the object after edit.

Comment: @Th0rndike - You can be sure the user will unfocus after edit because the premise of the question is that they will move on to apply a change to one or other (or all) of the other fields.